# How to test sparklr2 sample with curl?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

First to start on oAuth2 as a beginner, I run the sparklr2 sample, it works fine then I try to test some different kind of Authorization scenarios.

For reference the configure method of AuthorizationServerConfiguration class is:

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("esirius")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("secret")
            .and()
                .withClient("esirius-with-redirect")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .secret("secret")
                .redirectUris(esiriusRedirectUri)
            .and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "client_credentials")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "trust")
                .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
            .and()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
            .and()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("somesecret")
            .and()
                .withClient("my-less-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .and()
                .withClient("my-less-trusted-autoapprove-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .autoApprove(true);
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

The first I succeeded while running curl is the grant_type=client_credentials

```
%curl% -i -X POST "http://localhost:8002/oauth/token" -H "Accept: application/json" -u "my-client-with-registered-redirect:" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -d "scope=read"
```

response :

```
{"access_token":"3735d098-fb33-48da-8f87-a950e4bd3df2","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"read"}
```

Now I'm trying to test the grant_type=password scenario:

```
%curl% -i  -d "client_id=my-trusted-client" -d "username=marissa" -d "password=koala" -d "grant_type=password" -d "redirect_uri=http://a-dreuz/callback"  -H "Accept: application/json"  -X POST http://localhost:8002/oauth/token
```

and have the response:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I have tested a lot of combination whithout success, what's wrong with this request?
 I found that it's a good way to test request manualy with curl to understand the differents scenarios with oAuth2.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank @dave-syer to point out my mistake, I can request now using curl the grant_type=password scenario with success.    %curl% -i  -u "my-trusted-client-with-secret:somesecret"   -d "username=marissa" -d "password=koala" -d "grant_type=password"  -d "scope=read"  -H "Accept: application/json"  -X POST http://localhost:8002/oauth/token

Answer (score 0):

You haven't authenticated the client. You did in the first example so you know how to do it (just copy the `-u` parameter down into the second example).

Also there is no redirect URI in a password grant, so that parameter will be ignored and can be omitted (as can the client ID).